# Sort structure array on basis of an element in c++ by sort() function defined in algorithm header file

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have structure:-

```
typedef struct {
int x;
int y;
}point;
```

i declared array :-

```
point A[100];
```

i took inputs for A from user.
so how can we sort the array A on the basis of x element.
I know how to do it by writing a function.
But how to do it by using sort() function defined in algorithm.h in C++

Comment: Do you know how to write `operator<`?

Comment: Read more about [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) and what it uses for comparison. Then learn about [*operator overloading*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators).

Comment: No I don't know how to write operator< .

Comment: If you don't have a good beginners book yet, [then you should find one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Then read the chapter on operator overloading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a comparator function as the third argument of [`sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/).

Include `algorithm` of course.

```
#include<algorithm>
```

Define the comparator function. It should compare two points and return `true` if the first one should be before the second one (if first one is smaller than the second one) in the sorted array. The `sort` function in `<algorithm>` will use this comparator function to compare your items and put them in the right order. You can learn more about sorting algorithms [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm). If you need more advanced materials you can lookup "Introduction to Algorithms".

```
bool compare(const point& p1, const point& p2) {
    return p1.x < p2.x;
}
```

Use `sort` and pass your array and the function like this:

```
int main () {
    point A[100];
    std::sort(A, A+100, compare);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks Amir it worked,but as i am new to c++ can you explain how compare  function is working . and why you are not passing any argument to compare .As it's function prototype declaration contains 2 arguments p1 and p2.

Comment: @GauravAnand You're welcome. I updated the answer with a little more info. `sort` just need a function that could use it to compare two of your data-type. It will use this function as many times as possible with different items in your array to put them in the right order.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a compare function to `std::sort`.

```
point A[100];

std::sort(A, A+100, 
          [](const point& f, const point& s) -> bool{
              return f.x < s.x;
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

Write comparator:

```
inline bool ComparePoints(const point & first, const point & second) {
    return first.x < second.x;
}
```

After that you can call `std::sort()`:

```
std::sort(A, A + 100, ComparePoints);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using lambdas:

```
std::sort(std::begin(A),std::end(A),[](point const& l,point const& r){return l.x<r.x;});
```